# Yii 2 getOldAttribute() method not working in afterSave

Tags: activerecord, yii2

I have a `model` and I want to take an old the value of that model's field after save, I was using `getOldAttribute()` method and it always returns the latest value?

Code sample

```
class User extends ActiveRecord
{
    public function fields()
    {
       return [
          'id',
          'name',
          'email' //old value: example@example.com
       ];
    }
}

class UserService extends BaseService
{
    /**
     * Current user have email is `test@test.com`
     */
    public function update(User $user)
    {
       //before save
       $oldEmailBeforSave = $user->getOldAttribute('email'); //work fine and value is `example@example.com` 

       //handle update user
       $this->saveEntity($user)

       //after save
       $oldEmailAfterSave = $user->getOldAttribute('email'); //not work and value is `test@test.com`

    }

}
```

Comment: Some snap of your code will be helpful..!

Comment: I has added code sample @Gru

Comment: Solution temporary: Create an original user and work with it @@

Answer (score 3):

According to the docs you can use the second parameter of the `afterSave( $insert, $changedAttributes)` which holds the old values of the attributes that were changed and were saved.

Your code should look like below if you want to get the `email` fields old value if it was changed

```
public function afterSave( $insert, $changedAttributes ){
    parent::afterSave();
    if(!$insert){
        $oldEmail = $changedAttributes['email'];
        //do something here with the old email value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but in my model does not contain afterSave method, I handle every things in Service layer, could you take a look the code sample above

Comment: you need to add it there @dangchithao

Comment: have another way @Muhammad Omer Aslam

Answer (score 2):

When you save new attribute, it is no longer "old". `getOldAttribute()` represents state from database and allows you to compare whether and how attribute was changed between `find()` and `save()`. After calling `save()`, old attributes are refreshed, so `getOldAttribute()` will return the same as `getAttribute()`.

If you want to access old state of object, you need to clone it and use these methods on clone - `$cloned` will represent state of object before calling `save()`:

```
public function update(User $user)
{
   //before save
   $oldEmailBeforSave = $user->getOldAttribute('email'); // `example@example.com` 
   $cloned = clone $user;

   //handle update user
   $this->saveEntity($user)

   //after save
   $oldEmailAfterSave = $user->getOldAttribute('email'); // `test@test.com`
   $oldEmailAfterSave = $cloned->getOldAttribute('email'); // `example@example.com`

}
```

Comment: Yep, my temporary solution: Create an original user and work with it, I clone it, thank for your explanation ;) @rob006